# (fresh installation) should I remove Nouveuau before install NVIDIA driver?

Tags: drivers

(Ubuntu 16.04)
(GF9600GT)

Should I remove Nouveuau before install NVIDIA driver?

Comment: There is no need to remove nouveau. Install a driver from Ubuntu repositories. Do not download a driver from Nvidia site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to. Ubuntu will automatically switch to using the proprietary driver you install.

I also recommend that you avoid uninstalling `nouveau`, since there are sometimes problems with the NVIDIA driver installation. You might need to revert to `nouveau` while fixing the proprietary drivers. If it's uninstalled, it's an extra step (in a non-GUI environment most likely) to install them again.

Keep `nouveau` and install the proprietary drivers. You may want to check my [Q&A on NVIDIA driver installations in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/760934/274320) for a guide. (Yes, it says "Graphics Issues," but following the answer will help avoid any issues in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

Install drivers for this adapter this way:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Comment: Thanks, I did. I need 1680x1050, but maximum it offer is 1360x768. :(

Comment: It depends on a cable and connection. If you use DVI to VGA adater, you may need to add resolutions manually using xrandr.

Comment: Then look the site for directions. There must be an answer somewhere.