# Quirky user experience Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo T460p 8G RAM

Tags: 16.04, display, lenovo

I've been working with Ubuntu 16 (and 14 before that) on my new Lenovo t460P for some time now. While it's possible to work the user experience is inferior to what you get working with Windows on the same machine.

The main problem is with the responsiveness of the display. It's evident mostly on the browsers on the machine (FF and chrome), but also the general feel of the machine is "off".

I suspect that the OS is not taking full advantage of of the display hardware which should be quite good on this machine.

I have zero experience in tweaking display in Linux... where do I start?

1. How do I check the current display performance?
2. How do I check if the display card is active?
3. If not active - what do I do?

Adding the lshw -c video ouput:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1000000-f1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64)
```

Comment: Start by identifying hardware =)

Comment: Please enter the command  `sudo lshw -class video` -> this should show some information about your display hardware, and what driver is being used.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Added lshw output

Comment: You've got two graphics cards in your system - an NVidia card used for fast graphic response, and an integrated Intel card which does display graphics, but at a much lower speed/power consumption.  Ubuntu has mechanisms for allowing you to switch on demand (`nvidia-prime`), and several people have written about how to install the nvidia drivers.  Please see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/819322/fresh-installation-should-i-remove-nouveuau-before-install-nvidia-driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819322/fresh-installation-should-i-remove-nouveuau-before-install-nvidia-driver)